# Correcting this for-loop?

Tags: javascript

I am a student trying to learn.

The objective is to create a for-loop with variable `i` starting at 0 and it should increase by 1 each time through the loop. The loop should be running as long as `i` is less than limit.

On each iteration of the loop, the number `i` should be adding to the total variable.

```
total = 0

limit = 10

for (var i = 0; i < limit; total += i) {
    // log the numbers 0 through i
    console.log(i)
}
```

When I run this nothing but zeros appear.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you're not incrementing `i`, but `total`.

Comment: `i` is always zero, it never changes, what do you expect it to be - which part of your code do you expect will change the value of `i`?

Comment: You created an infinite loop by never incrementing `i`

Comment: you have a var called `limit`, and your comment states you think you are going to `log the numbers 0 through i` ... though you're always logging `i`, so that makes no sense either

Comment: for(declarations; condition to break loop; action that occurs after each loop) {
  do things
}

Answer (score 1):

In that loop your increment `total + 0` and `i` will be `0` always.

```
int total=0;
int limit=10;

for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    total += i ;
  }
console.log(total)
```

Comment: Mohammad. When I ran what you wrote above the numbers 0 through 9 logged.

Comment: However apparantely the solution of this textbook problem is 45, since we're adding everything together???

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop you need to specify what should happen after each iteration of the loop in the last section. Currently you are adding `i` to `total`, but never changing `i` so the loop will never end.

Judging by your attempt you are trying to add `i` to total each iteration of the loop for `limit` times.

So to correct it, it should look like this:

```
total = 0
limit = 10

for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    console.log(i)  // log the numbers 0 through i
    total += i  // add i to total each iteration
}
console.log(total)  // prints out the final result
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the incrementation in the wrong spot.

```
total = 0

limit = 10

for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
// log the numbers 0 through i
 total += i
 console.log(i)
}
```